# How do encounter card vampires work in combat?

Tags: fury-of-dracula

(third edition question)

Do you also draw 5 cards from the Dracula Combat Cards pack and continue with combat as you would with Dracula?

If so, what is the point of the Escape and Flee cards for a non-Dracula vampire?

Comment: One minor correction, IIRC, dracula draws 5 cards at the start of combat.

Comment: Checked the rules, indeed it is 5 cards for Dracula. It wasn't mentioned in Rules Reference though, only in L2P guide, so it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 3rd edition rules reference:

> Vampire Encounters
>
> Combat with a vampire can be initiated from
>   Dracula’s “New Vampire” and “Reckless Vampire” encounter cards. The
>   rules in this section apply only to vampire encounters; when the word
>   “Dracula” is used, it is referring to the Dracula player.
>
> † If a hunter either resolves a search action or is ambushed in a hideout or
>   lair and an encounter card is revealed that reads, “fight this
>   vampire,” a combat occurs.
>
> † Combat against vampires uses the same
>   rules as combat against Dracula with the following exceptions:
>
> - “New Vampire” and “Reckless Vampire” encounter cards have their own health
>     values. When one of these vampires suffers damage, it is tracked on
>     the card using damage tokens. If a vampire has a number of damage
>     tokens on its card equal to or greater than its health value, that
>     vampire is defeated.
> - When a vampire is defeated, its encounter card
>     is discarded. If combat ends without the vampire being defeated, the
>     damage it suffered remains on the card.
>
> † If Dracula plays “Escape as
>   Mist” or “Escape as Bat” before he has played a number of combat cards
>   greater than the number of despair tokens on the time track, the card
>   is canceled.
>
> - If Dracula resolves “Escape as Bat,” combat ends, but
>     neither Dracula nor the vampire are moved from their current
>     locations.

To summarise: combat is played out almost exactly the same, except fledgeling vampire tracks their own health and escape cards don't move it.

Also, if a combat ends and vampire wasn't defeated, it stays in location (retaining damage), and if revealed vampire reaches end of the Trail, it still can trigger its matured effect.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I need to learn to read between the lines in general when it comes to board game rules.

Comment: @skepticscript This wasn't explained in "Combat" section, as one might expect, but "Vampire Encounters" was mentioned under related topics in "Combat".
You know the game takes deduction seriously when it makes you deduce rules :)